# A productive set contains an infinite r.e. set.

Tags: logic, computability

I am having some trouble showing the following: 
If P is productive, then P contains an infinite r.e. set W. (It is part of a theorem from Soare's "Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees).

The proof in Soare goes as follows:

Let $W_n=\emptyset$, and $W_{h(x)}=W_x\cup \{p(x)\}$. Define
\begin{align*}
W=\{p(n), ph(n),ph^2(n),...\}.
\end{align*}

And that is it.

Note that h is a recursive (total) function, that p is an injective, total, recursive, productive function for the set P.

I understand why $W\subseteq P$, and that $W$ is an inifite set. I can not see clearly why $W$ is r.e. (recursively enumerable). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Rule of thumb: if we're looking at a recursive definition, we should probably use the Recursion Theorem. There are different ways to "program" the construction; and choosing a suitable one is part of the fun.